# glUtilsParamSize error when opening new activity

Tags: java, android

I have one problem. When i run my app, i want to open new activity with button. That works with one activity,but the other activity(two buttons in main menu,one works other not) just closes the app. Here is the code of that activity,and the logcat of errors. Logcat says there is problem with glutilsparamsize

My problem is that it doesn't want to open activity pronadi. My buttons Opis and Izlaz work and they open activity opis and izlaz button exits,but button pronadi says "com.example.shromid. stopped" and closes the app. I want to open activity pronadi.

**LOGCAT errors**

```
 01-31 09:49:47.351 4576-4596/com.example.shromid E/eglCodecCommon: 
 glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
 01-31 09:49:47.352 4576-4596/com.example.shromid E/eglCodecCommon: 
 glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
 01-31 09:49:47.360 4576-4596/com.example.shromid E/eglCodecCommon: 
 glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
 01-31 09:49:47.360 4576-4596/com.example.shromid E/eglCodecCommon: 
 glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
```

Activity that i want to open

```
package com.example.shromid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pronadi extends Activity {
    Spinner kboja;
    Spinner ktekstura;
    Spinner koblik;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    List<String>gljive=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pronadi);
        kboja = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.kboja);
        ktekstura = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ktekstura);
        koblik = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.koblik);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(Pronadi.this);
        prepareData();
        prepareData1();
        prepareData2();

        kboja.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        koblik.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        ktekstura.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

        public void prepareData() {
        gljive=db.getKlobuk_Boja();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Pronadi.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,android.R.id.text1,gljive);
        kboja.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

        public void prepareData1() {
        gljive=db.getKlobuk_Oblik();
        adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Pronadi.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,android.R.id.text1,gljive);
        koblik.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }
    public void prepareData2(){
        gljive=db.getKlobuk_Tekstura();
        adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Pronadi.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,android.R.id.text1,gljive);
        ktekstura.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
}
```

Activity with buttons to open activity

```html
package com.example.shromid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        izlaz();
        otvoriopis();
        otvoripronadi();
    }
    public Button btnopis;
        public void otvoriopis(){
            btnopis=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnopis);
            btnopis.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent otvoriopis= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Opis.class);
                    startActivity(otvoriopis);
                }
            });

        }
    public Button btnpronadi;
        public void otvoripronadi(){
            btnpronadi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpronadi);
            btnpronadi.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent otvoripronadi= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Pronadi.class);
                    startActivity(otvoripronadi);
            }
        });
    }
    public Button btnizlaz;
        public void izlaz(){
            btnizlaz=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnizlaz);
            btnizlaz.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

android manifest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shromid">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_ikona"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="ShromID"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".Opis" />
        <activity android:name=".Pronadi"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main activity xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pozadina2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.shromid.MainActivity">
<!-- Gumbovi u glavnom meniju -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnpronadi"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gumbpronadi"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnopis"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnopis"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gumbopis"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnizlaz"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnpronadi" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnizlaz"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gumbizlaz"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnopis" />
    <!-- Kraj gumbova u glavnom meniju -->
    <!-- Logo u glavnom meniju -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gljiveprobna"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnpronadi"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That it not the error that causes the crash. Search the right exception in logcat

Comment: add the code of the onClick of the buttons and the manifest

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler then i don't know where is error,nowhere else I get the message of error,app just stops.

Comment: @PavelB. i added manifest and activity with buttons

Comment: All looks OK, the only thing that can be that there is an error in the layout XML. Perhaps the buttons ids are incorrect?

Comment: Every button id is correct,name of them. Everything is ok,it has no errors but the app closes itself when you press the button to open pronadi_activity

Comment: Really strange - can you add main activity layout xml. Btw You see any unhandled exception in the logcat?

Comment: Here is the main activity layout xml. No,i can copy you whole logcat,i can't se any unhandled exception

Comment: I just used what You provided to create a new project and it works ok. The app exits only when i press izlaz... Try adding log messages in each method and see what is being called before the app is closed

Comment: No no man, i don't want to exit. My problem is that it doesn't want to open activity pronadi. My buttons Opis and Izlaz work and they open activity opis and izlaz button exits,but button pronadi says "com.example.shromid. stopped" and closes the app. I want to open activity pronadi.

Comment: yes, the pronadi opened ok in my test, but i had to comment out most of the code. Add log message in the beginning of each method in the pronadi activity, and see what method causes the crash

Comment: I don't understand how you mean comment out. And how do i add log message in the beggining? Can you give me a hint about that cause i'm new with android developing